# woocommerce : Unable to override single-product template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to override woo commerce single product template but it won't get overridden.

I have done the following steps:

1. Added file inside my theme directory.

[image]

2. Added support for Woo-commerce in my functions.php file

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse319485_add_woocommerce_support' );

function wpse319485_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
```

3. Made sure the debug mode is off in config file

```
define( 'WC_TEMPLATE_DEBUG_MODE', false );
```

4. Checked the status of templates over-riden
   [image]
5. Added an h1 tag with test text in it.
   [image]
   I even tried deleting everything but the default template is loaded.

What am I missing ?

Comment: If your theme uses `woocommerce.php`it takes priority of templates. check if the default template actually is `single-product.php`

Comment: else, in the top of single-product template file, there should be instructions on how to override it

Comment: I don't have `woocommerce.php` in my theme file. Theme file structure : https://imgur.com/pzMTXgn

Comment: Also, my email overrides work. Its the single-product page which seems to be not working.

Comment: elementor has a build-in WooCommerce Builder right? maybe that is overwriting you template selection. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F2gyAeZdU9s

Comment: I checked, I have no single product page designed by elementor theme builder. Earlier I had the product template set by using toolset.com but then I removed it and then it was defaulted to woocommerce plugin. When I make changes in the woocommerce plugin folder to test, I can see the changes being applied. This means that the default plugin is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are still facing this problem. I ran into the very same. After a very frustrating day, tempted to hack the plugin files, I ended up adding woocommerce.php to my theme, containing:

```
if ( is_product() ) {
wc_get_template( 'woocommerce/single-product.php' );
}else{
//For ANY product archive.
//Product taxonomy, product search or /shop landing
wc_get_template( 'woocommerce/archive-product.php' );
}
```

This is an adaptation of what I found here:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/archive-productphp-template-overwrite-not-working/

It did not work without adding
woocommerce/